# Regex number range

Tags: java, regex, xml, bean-io

I'm using the BeanIO framework to parse files. In my XML code, i want 
a  3-digit field to only contain a specific range of numbers, from 000 to 199.

I've tried the following (the field must be manipulated as a String) :

```
<field name="recordType" length="3" minOccurs = "0" regex = "[0-1][0-9][0-9]"/>
```

It doesn't seem to be working.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the unnecessary spaces.

Comment: You probably need anchors `^[0-1][0-9][0-9]$` or else `1999` is valid.

Comment: No, still not working.

Comment: I see, consult the BeanIO docs.

Comment: Please post a sample file that isn't matching. I think that a concrete example at this point may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe you might want to design an expression to cover some other single and double digits, beside three digits, such as:

```
^([0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9])$
```

or,

```
^([0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})$
```

or,

```
^(?:[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/woBzMs/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "^(?:[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9])$";
        final String string = "0\n"
             + "1\n"
             + "2\n"
             + "00\n"
             + "11\n"
             + "22\n"
             + "99\n"
             + "100\n"
             + "000\n"
             + "199\n"
             + "200";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: 0
Full match: 1
Full match: 2
Full match: 00
Full match: 11
Full match: 22
Full match: 99
Full match: 100
Full match: 000
Full match: 199
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]